# Devolver la fila y la columna en la que se encontro el caracter no numerico o estado de rechazo de la tabla de estados (Automatas)

Tags: c

Buenas una consulta tengo que obtener la fila y la columna del estado de rechazo de un caracter no valido no se como podria hacer , un ejemplo puede ser 3+a+5 donde diga la tabla 3 caracter numerico +  operador , a caracter no valido y me devuelva la fila y la columna donde se encontro , 5 caracter numerico asi debe decir la tabla no se como poder obtenerla esas dimensiones en la que se encuentra el error. Recorre un archivo de texto donde un ejemplo es que tenga ese archivo de texto 3+a+5.

```
  /**
         * Ejemplo del autómata finito determinístico que
         * reconoce el lenguaje de las expresiones regulares (suma del lenguaje de los enternosNumericos y de las operaciones*
         */
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        //#include "reconocedor.h"
        int T(int q, int x);
        int conseguirIndice(int x);
        void vaciarString(char str[]);
        void conseguirToken(char token[20], int estado_actual);
        #define LENGTH 50
        
        int main(int argc, char **argv)
        {
            int x;
            int estado_actual = 0;
            char string[LENGTH]; // Tamaño máximo de la cadena (ajusta según tus necesidades)
            memset(string,0,LENGTH);
            const char *nombreArchivo = "archivo.txt";
            FILE *archivo = fopen(nombreArchivo, "r");
            char token[20];
            if (archivo == NULL)
            {
                printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("+-------------+----------------------+\n");
            printf("|En el codigo | Token                |\n");
            printf("+-------------+----------------------+\n");
        
            int i = 0;
            x = fgetc(archivo);
        
            while (x != EOF)
            {
                if (x == '\n')
                {   
                    conseguirToken(token, estado_actual+1);
                    printf("| %-11s | %-20.*s |\n", string, 20, token);
                    memset(string,0,LENGTH);
                    estado_actual = 0;
                    i = 0;
                    printf("+-------------+----------------------+\n");
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("+-------------+----------------------+\n");
                    printf("|En el codigo | Token                |\n");
                    printf("+-------------+----------------------+\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    estado_actual = T(estado_actual, x);
                    if (estado_actual == 4 || estado_actual == 2)
                    {
                        conseguirToken(token, estado_actual);
                        printf("| %-11s | %-20.*s |\n", string, 20, token);
                        //printf("ACEPTADA: %s\n", string);
                        ungetc(x, archivo);
                        
                        memset(string,0,LENGTH);
                        estado_actual = 0;
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    
                    else if (estado_actual == -1)
                    {
                        printf("RECHAZADA\n");
                        printf("Caracter no válido: %c\n", (char)x); // Imprime el carácter no válido
                        estado_actual = 0;
                        memset(string,0,LENGTH);
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        char caracter = (char)x;
                        string[i] = caracter;
                        // printf("%c\n", caracter);
                        //for ( int j=0; j<6; j++) {
                        //  printf("%c\n", string[j]);
                        //}
                        // printf("Cadena: %s\n", string);
                        i++;
                    }
                    
                }
                x = fgetc(archivo);
            }
        
            fclose(archivo); // Cierra el archivo
            if (estado_actual == 1 || estado_actual == 3)
            {
                conseguirToken(token, estado_actual+1);
                printf("| %-11s | %-20.*s |\n", string, 20, token);
                printf("+-------------+----------------------+\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("RECHAZADA: %s\n", string);
            }
            return 0;
        }
        int conseguirIndice(int x)
        {
            if (x >= 48 && x <= 57)
            {
                return 0; // Dígitos del 0 al 9
            }
            else if (x >= 40 && x <= 43 || x == 45 || x == 47)
            {
                return 1; // Caracteres operadores [(, ), +, *, - , /]
            }
            else {
                return -1; // Caracteres no válidos
            }
        
        }
        
        void conseguirToken(char token[20], int estado_actual) {
            if (estado_actual == 2) {
                strcpy(token, "Constante numerica");
            } else {
                strcpy(token, "Operador");
            }
            
        }
        int T(int q, int x)
        {
            int indice = conseguirIndice(x);
        
            static int tabla[5][2] = {
                {1, 3},
                {1, 2},
                {-1, -1},
                {4, 4},
                {-1, -1}};
        
            if (indice == -1) {
                return -1; // Caracter no válido
            } else {
                return tabla[q][indice];
            }
        }
```

cualquier ayuda bienvenida gracias !